# Java - compilation errors on a method call

Tags: java, xml

When I try and run my code I immediately receive compilation errors because of my method call.

The class is `xmlWriter.java` and the method is `updateFile()` so it looks like this:

```
//call method to update
xmlWriter.updateFile(environment,doc);
```

The method updateFile passes the Environment environment which is a .java class and it passes Document doc for document builder

However the error I am getting is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The local variable environment may not have been initialized
The local variable doc may not have been initialized

Yet my method, as a whole, looks like:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    //declare new object of class
    XmlWriter xmlWriter = new XmlWriter();  

    Environment environment;

    Document doc;
    //call method to update
    xmlWriter.updateFile(environment,doc);

    //call method to export
}
```

It doesn't look right to me but I can't see another way of doing it - could anyone take a look  - It's to do with what goes through the parameters I know but I've never ran into this issue before :s

** EDIT **
I changed to what I had before so it says:

```
Environment environment = null;
Document doc = null;
```

Now when I debug it goes past line 40 fine:

```
xmlWriter.updateFile(environment,doc);
```

Once I get to line 270 in the updateFile method

```
Node enviro = doc.getElementsByTagName("environment").item(0);
```

I get a null pointer exception for both lines - I assume that is because I have set doc to null so thats now making it an issue?

Comment: Don't try to run your code if it doesn't even compile. Open the Markers or Problems view of your Eclipse IDE, and fix all the compilation errors listed there before even thinking about running your code.

Comment: Initialize environment and doc with "null". Read the compilation error.

Comment: I did that but I never considered it would work if I already gave it a predetermined null value - perhaps I should of tried it before posting rather than second guessing myself - Thanks for the advice

Comment: Java provides default values only for class fields (and possible arrays)

Comment: @user3373261: you need to think about what the program should do. Simply fixing compilation errors won't make the program work. If some method is designed to add two numbers and give you back the result, you can't just pass null to this method and expect anything meaningful as a result. You need to pass the numbers that you want to add. Only you know what the code should do, and what the xmlWriter.updateFile() method does with its arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an IDE such as Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/). It will help you resolve these simple bugs.

The reason your code is not compiling is because 'environment' and 'doc' are not initialized (as it says in the error...).

```
Environment environment = null;

Document doc = null;
```

Should solve this exception...

Comment: Yeah I changed it to that Roland as its what I originally had and it still isn't working :(

Comment: Well it should solve the issue you posted here on StackExchange. If you have another problem you should post another question. When you get a NullPointerException it means that you have not linked your variable to an existing object. See how you have `XmlWriter xmlWriter = new XmlWriter()`? The word 'new' means you have created a new object--hence why it does not give a NullPointerException because the variable xmlWriter is linked to the newly created object. I would recommend Googling around a bit more and find some examples online.